# install numpy for python 3.4 in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, numpy

I have python 2.7, and I installed beside it python 3.4, but python 3.4 has not numpy package. When I use sudo pip install -U numpy, it install it in python2.7 location. How can I install numpy for python 3.4 in a machine that has already python 2.7?

Comment: Use virtualenv or  `python3-pip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, to update a package for python3.4 you have to `sudo pip3 install -U numpy` (note the `pip3`).

It might be the case that you still have to install pip3 first (not sure if it is bundled). Probably for that you have to `sudo apt-get install python-pip3` or something. If you have a recent Ubuntu (I believe starting from 14.10), then you already have python 3.4 when you first boot up Ubuntu, as well as `pip3` pre-installed.

You can also install through ubuntu's package manager, but if you want an OS independent way, you can just use `pip3`.

Answer (score 2):

Just install numpy for Python 3 in Software center or in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```